# Is it possible to simulate multi-touch mouse down events?

Tags: mouse, multi-touch

I'm wondering if there's some application that allows you to simulate mouse-down events?

I looked at BetterTouchTool and it can bind to specific actions, but I can't do something like Hold Down a mouse button which simulates "3 fingers being pressed down, then moving the mouse sideways to activate switching between spaces, or moving the mouse up/down to simulate mission control/show desktop".

Comment: It looks like this still is an issue - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/108163/can-i-simulate-multi-touch-input-on-a-mac?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

There kind of is. Your question says "simulate mouse-down events", that's what's being covered in my answer. I used an application back in 2010, and I'm pleasantly surprised it's still being updated, and supports Mountain Lion.

It's called [Mac Auto Mouse Click](http://www.murgaa.com/mac-auto-mouse-click/), and it's pretty configurable. You can set it to click anywhere on the screen and remember the position, and execute a whole series of commands, including keystrokes. It's also fairly simple to use. Here's a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

It is however limited in that it can only perform simple mouse-clicks, here's the full list:

> - Left Mouse Button Click.
> - Right Mouse Button Click.
> - Middle Mouse Button Click.
> - Shift + Left Mouse Button Click.
> - Shift + Right Mouse Button Click.
> - Shift + Middle Mouse Button Click.
> - Double Left Button Click
> - Type Text Automatically, like a Mac Auto Typer.