# Can I simulate multi-touch input on a Mac?

Tags: mac, trackpad, multi-touch, magic-trackpad, accessibility

With iOS's accessibility features, it is possible to pretend the user is using multiple fingers or making certain gestures while in reality they are only using one finger.

Is there any way I can simulate multi-touch trackpad gestures on a Mac?

(Note: While this can be used for accessibility purposes, I'm specifically thinking of using this to two-finger-scroll while using my Monoprice drawing tablet. An answer that fulfills that function without working in all circumstances will also be accepted.)

Comment: Can you draw two separate lines simultaneously on the Monoprice tablet (using fingers or sylii) in the graphics application of your choice?

Comment: @IconDaemon No. I'm probably not looking for a tablet-specific solution, though.

Comment: I'm not sure this can help you, but it might be worth a shot: http://www.jitouch.com

Comment: @Frizlab Doesn't look like it, but thanks for trying. :)

Answer (score 2):

[BetterTouchTool](http://blog.boastr.net/) lets you create custom gestures, with custom actions. There are a variety of single-finger gestures:

[image: A list of the gestures in BTT.]

Have a look at it, and see if it suits your need.

Comment: I checked before posting this question. It doesn't.